# How to add a variable into a jQuery addClass function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to jQuery but learning. I am trying to do something simple (I think) but struggling. I am trying to add a var into Jquery to customise an specific element.

I need to add 'styler' class to my div which has the id="spinner7" like -

```
$('#spinner7').addClass('styler');
```

However the number can vary so I need to add it to the end of #spinner. I have tried things like below but no joy. Can anyone help please.

```
var ctrl = '7';
$('#spinner +ctrl').addClass('styler');
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the string: `$('#spinner' + ctrl)`. Alternatively if you want to use modern code standard and don't need IE support: ```$(`#spinner${ctrl}`)```

Answer (score 0):

**Template literals**

```
var ctrl = '7';
$(`#spinner${ctrl}`).addClass('styler');
```

**Or**

```
var ctrl = '7';
$('#spinner' + ctrl).addClass('styler');
```

Comment: brilliant will give it a try I see now